# How to retain git check in history before specific commit?

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-rewrite-history

Need help to get back git checking history which visual studio saves by all  commit. One of my team member pushed all code again so it removed  the history.
So Any way to get back all the history before this commit ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little unclear, because there's no reason why "pushing all code" should wipe history.  It sounds like your coworker performed a force push (perhaps because they didn't understand that they needed to pull and merge before pushing).

If your local repo previously had the history, then that history should still be there.  The easiest way to access it may be via the reflog.  Try

```
git reflog
```

It will show the most recent commits you've had checked out, one per line.  If you can find one from the original history, you can check it out, such as by

```
git checkout HEAD@{1}
```

(the reflog output will tell you what number to use to retrieve a given commit).

You also might be able to use a branch-specific reflog

```
git reflog master
...
git checkout master@{2}
```

The reflog is not shared, so only an individual clone that has seen the history you want to retrieve can do this.